# How to set static IPv6 IP address to embedded Linux board using ifconfig (busybox)?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

We want to set static IPv6 IP to custom embedded Linux board. So far we could enable IPv6 in Linux kernel and Busybox.

We could test that kernel is IPv6 ready. We tried to configure a static IP using `ifconfig` (Busybox) as mentioned below.

```
$ ifconfig eth0 2002:C0A8:103::
```

but it throws following error:

> bad port spec error

Any suggestions/pointers?

Comment: Could you check that you have IPv6 in this kernel? `cat /proc/net/if_inet6`

Comment: That's not a valid IPv6 address.

Comment: @Artiom if i cat if_inet6 file output is as follows `00000000000000000000000000000001 01 80 10 80 lo
fe800000000000007e669dfffe1d6f09 02 40 20 80 eth0
`

Answer (score 1):

I think your `ifconfig` syntax is not correct. Try this one:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2002:C0A8:103::/64
```

Probably you should change the mask to something else.

You can find more details on how to configure IPv6 interfaces here:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO